# django not able to post data

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

This is my index.html

```
<html>
        <body>
        <p>Please select Team from below:</p>
        <form action="teamspage/"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
          <select name="teams">
            <option value="astra">Astra</option>
            <option value="everest">Everest</option>
            <option value="pulse">Pulse</option>
            <option value="gravity">Gravity</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('piplanner/index.html')
    context = {
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def teamspage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse("Got it new team")
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^index/', include('piplanner.urls')),
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^teamspage/', include('piplanner.urls')),
        ]
```

piplanner urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.teamspage, name='teamspage'),

]
```

On submit request is not going to teamspage view. Please let me know what is wrong with code?
I am trying get method which returns form of drop down and on selection value it should go to teamspage url

Comment: Is the shown `views.py` part of `piplanner`-app? Can you add the `piplanner/urls.py`?

Comment: @wfehr Yes views are part of piplanner.

Comment: Mh, maybe your problem is the urls.py of piplanner. They are both set to the url "/piplanner/", and since index is the first entrance, it gets called. Try changing your url for `views.teamspage` and change the action in the html to it.